# What does 'bear' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> German NPs are marked for case, which signals the role of the NP in a
>   phrase (e.g., sentential subject, direct object, nominal complement,
>   etc.). Although an entire NP will bear a particular case, it is
>   typically the determiner (or adjective) in the NP rather than the N
>   itself that is inflected for case.

I think in above paragraph (from book [German: a linguistic introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521618037) page 119) the verb bear means [to show something; to carry something so that it can be seen](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bear_1?q=bear). Is it correct?

Comment: Note, to ask that question you should say "What does 'bear' mean?", instead of "what means bear"

Answer (score 2):

It's a figurative sense, **to support** or **to take, to accept** or **to sustain** or **to be marked by** as in

> Prepositions do not typically bear one of the four  metrical stresses in early Germanic poetic meter.

Comment: In origin, _bear_ means _carry_, as in many Indo-European languages. But it is almost obsolete in the literal sense of picking up an object and carrying it. It is however still in use in several generalised or figurative senses.